# Java Script вызов асинхронной функции

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, как сделать, что бы она сама себя не вызывала, а можно было бы её вызвапть?

```
(async function main() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(proxyurl + url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            },
        });

        let result = await response.json();
        for (let i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
            console.log(result[i].id);
        }
        id = result[i].id
        document.getElementById('arr').textContent = (id)

        let urlIssue = 'https://sad.myjetbrains.com/youtrack/api/issues/' + id + '?fields=summary,description';


        let objSel = document.getElementById('task')
        objSel.options[i] = new Option(id);


    } catch (err) {
        //console.error(err);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Превратите самовызов в декларацию, отредактировав первую и последнюю строчки:

```
async function main() {
  // Остальной код
}

main(); // Теперь её можно вызвать.
```

Comment: можно только последнюю редактировать `()`

Comment: То есть убрать только последние скобки? Но если оставить первую пару скобок, декларация превратится в выражение и мы получим `ReferenceError: main is not defined`.

Comment: Да, это @Grundy похоже перепутал